# Levenstein distance from particular group of numbers

Tags: algorithm

My input are three numbers - a number `s` and the beginning `b` and end `e` of a range with `0 <= s,b,e <= 10^1000`. The task is to find the minimal Levenstein distance between `s` and all numbers in range `[b, e]`. It is not necessary to find the number minimizing the distance, the minimal distance is sufficient.

Obviously I have to read the numbers as string, because standard C++ type will not handle such large numbers. Calculating the Levenstein distance for every number in the possibly huge range is not feasible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rewording: you are finding the distance of closest number to a specified value `S` that is in a specified integer range `[B,E]`, the distance being the Levenhstein distance (edit distance) in base-10?

Comment: That is not easy. You might get more answers on [cstheory.se]

Comment: yes that's what I mean, just my english is not so well - passive knowledge :)

Comment: Do you want the closest element as well, or just its distance from `s`?

Comment: Distance would be enough

Comment: You could make an `O(L^D)` algorithm quite easily where `L` is the input length and `D` is the output distance. Just try out all different edits.

Comment: The problem "is the distance less than `x`" is definitely in `NP`. Proving it `NP-hard` would be more difficult.

Comment: It cannot be solved faster than cubic, as the algorithm degenerates to calculating the distance for one-element ranges. More generally, there is an `O(L^3 R)` solution where `R` is the length of the range (which could be pretty big).

Comment: A range search is basically a bunch of prefix ranges (`[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]`), so if you have a good algoritm for searching with a given prefix, you can use it for the range search.

Comment: Is `s` in the range or may it be outside of it?

Comment: Ignore the question above - if `b <= s <= e` the minimal distance is obviously zero.

Comment: @JanDvorak and others: It's not NP-hard, see my algorithm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDIT 10/8/2013: Some cases considered in the DP algorithm actually don't need to be considered after all, though considering them does not lead to incorrectness :)]**

In the following I describe an algorithm that takes O(N^2) time, where N is the largest number of **digits** in any of b, e, or s.  Since all these numbers are limited to 1000 digits, this means at most a few million basic operations, which will take **milliseconds** on any modern CPU.

Suppose s has n digits.  In the following, "between" means "inclusive"; I will say "strictly between" if I mean "excluding its endpoints".  Indices are 1-based.  x[i] means the ith digit of x, so e.g. x[1] is its first digit.

### Splitting up the problem

The first thing to do is to break up the problem into a series of subproblems in which each b and e have the same number of digits.  Suppose e has k >= 0 more digits than s: break up the problem into k+1 subproblems.  E.g. if b = 5 and e = 14032, create the following subproblems:

- b = 5, e = 9
- b = 10, e = 99
- b = 100, e = 999
- b = 1000, e = 9999
- b = 10000, e = 14032

We can solve each of these subproblems, and take the minimum solution.

### The easy cases: the middle

The easy cases are the ones in the middle.  Whenever e has k >= 1 more digits than b, there will be k-1 subproblems (e.g. 3 above) in which b is a power of 10 and e is the next power of 10, minus 1.  Suppose b is 10^m.  Notice that choosing any digit between 1 and 9, followed by any m digits between 0 and 9, produces a number x that is in the range b <= x <= e.  Furthermore there are no numbers in this range that cannot be produced this way.  The minimum Levenshtein distance between s (or in fact any given length-n digit string that doesn't start with a 0) and *any* number x in the range 10^m <= x <= 10^(m+1)-1 is necessarily abs(m+1-n), since if m+1 >= n it's possible to simply choose the first n digits of x to be the same as those in s, and delete the remainder, and if m+1 < n then choose the first m+1 to be the same as those in s and insert the remainder.

**In fact we can deal with *all* these subproblems in a single constant-time operation:** if the smallest "easy" subproblem has b = 10^m and the largest "easy" subproblem has b = 10^u, then the minimum Levenshtein distance between s and any number in any of these ranges is m-n if n < m, n-u if n > u, and 0 otherwise.

### The hard cases: the end(s)

The hard cases are when b and e are not restricted to have the form b = 10^m and e = 10^(m+1)-1 respectively.  Any master problem can generate at most two subproblems like this: either two "ends" (resulting from a master problem in which b and e have different numbers of digits, such as the example at the top) or a single subproblem (i.e. the master problem itself, which didn't need to be subdivided at all because b and e already have the same number of digits).  Note that due to the previous splitting of the problem, we can assume that the subproblem's b and e have the same number of digits, which we will call m.

### Super-Levenshtein!

What we will do is design a variation of the Levenshtein DP matrix that calculates the minimum Levenshtein distance between a given digit string (s) and *any* number x in the range b <= x <= e.  Despite this added "power", the algorithm will still run in O(n^2) time :)

First, observe that if b and e have the same number of digits and b != e, then it must be the case that they consist of some number q >= 0 of identical digits at the left, followed by a digit that is larger in e than in b.  Now consider the following procedure for generating a random digit string x:

1. Set x to the first q digits of b.
2. Append a randomly-chosen digit d between b[i] and e[i] to x.
3. If d == b[i], we "hug" the lower bound:

   - For i from q+1 to m:

     - If b[i] == 9 then append b[i].  **[EDIT 10/8/2013: Actually this can't happen, because we chose q so that e[i] will be larger then b[i], and there is no digit larger than 9!]**
     - Otherwise, flip a coin:

       - Heads: Append b[i].
       - Tails: Append a randomly-chosen digit d > b[i], then goto 6.
   - Stop.
4. Else if d == e[i], we "hug" the upper bound:

   - For i from q+1 to m:

     - If e[i] == 0 then append e[i].  **[EDIT 10/8/2013: Actually this can't happen, because we chose q so that b[i] will be smaller then e[i], and there is no digit smaller than 0!]**
     - Otherwise, flip a coin:

       - Heads: Append e[i].
       - Tails: Append a randomly-chosen digit d < e[i], then goto 6.
   - Stop.
5. Otherwise (if d is strictly between b[i] and e[i]), drop through to step 6.
6. Keep appending randomly-chosen digits to x until it has m digits.

The basic idea is that after including all the digits that you must include, you can either "hug" the lower bound's digits for as long as you want, or "hug" the upper bound's digits for as long as you want, and as soon as you decide to stop "hugging", you can thereafter choose any digits you want.  For suitable random choices, this procedure will generate all and only the numbers x such that b <= x <= e.

In the "usual" Levenshtein distance computation between two strings s and x, of lengths n and m respectively, we have a rectangular grid from (0, 0) to (n, m), and at each grid point (i, j) we record the Levenshtein distance between the prefix s[1..i] and the prefix x[1..j].  The score at (i, j) is calculated from the scores at (i-1, j), (i, j-1) and (i-1, j-1) using bottom-up dynamic programming.  To adapt this to treat x as *one of a set of possible strings* (specifically, a digit string corresponding to a number between b and e) instead of a particular given string, what we need to do is record not one but two scores for each grid point: one for the case where we assume that the digit at position j was chosen to hug the lower bound, and one where we assume it was chosen to hug the upper bound.  The 3rd possibility (step 5 above) doesn't actually require space in the DP matrix because we can work out the minimal Levenshtein distance for the entire rest of the input string immediately, very similar to the way we work it out for the "easy" subproblems in the first section.

### Super-Levenshtein DP recursion

Call the overall minimal score at grid point (i, j) v(i, j).  Let diff(a, b) = 1 if characters a and b are different, and 0 otherwise.  Let inrange(a, b..c) be 1 if the character a is in the range b..c, and 0 otherwise.  The calculations are:

```
# The best Lev distance overall between s[1..i] and x[1..j]
v(i, j) = min(hb(i, j), he(i, j))

# The best Lev distance between s[1..i] and x[1..j] obtainable by
# continuing to hug the lower bound
hb(i, j) = min(hb(i-1, j)+1, hb(i, j-1)+1, hb(i-1, j-1)+diff(s[i], b[j]))

# The best Lev distance between s[1..i] and x[1..j] obtainable by
# continuing to hug the upper bound
he(i, j) = min(he(i-1, j)+1, he(i, j-1)+1, he(i-1, j-1)+diff(s[i], e[j]))
```

At the point in time when v(i, j) is being calculated, we will also calculate the Levenshtein distance resulting from choosing to "stop hugging", i.e. by choosing a digit that is strictly in between b[j] and e[j] (if j == q) or (if j != q) is either above b[j] or below e[j], and thereafter freely choosing digits to make the suffix of x match the suffix of s as closely as possible:

```
# The best Lev distance possible between the ENTIRE STRINGS s and x, given that
# we choose to stop hugging at the jth digit of x, and have optimally aligned
# the first i digits of s to these j digits
sh(i, j) = if j >= q then shc(i, j)+abs(n-i-m+j)
           else infinity

shc(i, j) = if j == q then
              min(hb(i, j-1)+1, hb(i-1, j-1)+inrange(s[i], (b[j]+1)..(e[j]-1)))
            else
              min(hb(i, j-1)+1, hb(i-1, j-1)+inrange(s[i], (b[j]+1)..9),
                  he(i, j-1)+1, he(i-1, j-1)+inrange(s[i], (0..(e[j]-1)))
```

The formula for shc(i, j) doesn't need to consider "downward" moves, since such moves don't involve any digit choice for x.

The overall minimal Levenshtein distance is the minimum of v(n, m) and sh(i, j), for all 0 <= i <= n and 0 <= j <= m.

### Complexity

Take N to be the largest number of digits in any of s, b or e.  The original problem can be split in linear time into at most 1 set of easy problems that collectively takes O(1) time to solve and 2 hard subproblems that each take O(N^2) time to solve using the super-Levenshtein algorithm, so overall the problem can be solved in O(N^2) time, i.e. time proportional to the square of the number of digits.

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot that I asked about it. I use your tips and it passes all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

A first idea to speed up the computation (works if `|e-b|` is not too large):

- Question: how much can the Levestein distance change when we compare `s` with `n` and then with `n+1`?
- Answer: not too much!

Let's see the dynamic-programming tables for `s = 12007` and two consecutive `n`

```
n = 12296

0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 0 1 2 3 4 
2 1 0 1 2 3 
3 2 1 1 2 3 
4 3 2 2 2 3 
5 4 3 3 3 3
```

and

```
n = 12297

0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 0 1 2 3 4 
2 1 0 1 2 3 
3 2 1 1 2 3 
4 3 2 2 2 3 
5 4 3 3 3 2
```

As you can see, **only the last column changes**, since `n` and `n+1` have the same digits, except for the last one.

If you have the dynamic-programming table for the edit-distance of `s = 12001` and `n = 12296`, you already have the table for `n = 12297`, you just need to update the last column!

Obviously if `n = 12299` then `n+1 = 12300` and you need to update the last 3 columns of the previous table.. but this happens just once every 100 iteration.

In general, you have to

- update the last column on every iterations (so, length(s) cells)
- update the second-to-last too, once every 10 iterations
- update the third-to-last, too, once every 100 iterations

so let `L = length(s)` and `D = e-b`. First you compute the edit-distance between `s` and `b`. Then you can find the minimum Levenstein distance over `[b,e]` looping over every integer in the interval. There are `D` of them, so the execution time is about:

[image]

Now since

[image]

we have an algorithm wich is

[image]